# regex to filter out numbers in seo url

Tags: php, regex

I have some urls like these below

```
http://www.bla-bla.com/hello-world/blah/1345346-asfasdf.html
http://www.bla-bla.com/hello-world/454536556-asdf-rtrthr-dssdfg.html
http://www.bla-bla.com/hello-world/bla/how/what/26609768-nmbbasdf.html
```

IF the url has a slash followed by numbers, I need to return the just numbers
so the result must be

```
1345346
454536556
26609768
```

How can I get everything but the numbers from urls

Comment: What have you tried? You can use [Regex Tester](http://www.regextester.com/) to easily test your regular expressions.

Comment: Which is it: "return the just numbers" or "get everything but the numbers"?

Comment: How are you doing your `RewriteRule`?

Comment: @MRAB both are wrong you said, I want a regex as "get the numbers followed by a slash(/) until a dash(-)

Comment: @George Cummins, I tried `/\/(\d+).*\.html$/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those are the only numbers in your URL, you can simply use `/\d+/`, which stands for "Any digit one or more times".

If you need to specifically group out the numbers in the final part of the string, you can use something more like this: `/\/(\d+).*\.html$/`, which stands for "A group of digits, following a literal forward slash '/', followed by any characters and .html at the end of a string", and capture group 1 would contain it.

As per request from comment: to get the numbers preceded by a forward slash `/` and ending with a hyphen `-`, just use this: `/(?<=\/)\d+(?=\-)/`, which can be broken down as:

```
(?<=\/)  # Look before the group for a forward slash, but don't add it to the capture group.
\d+      # Match one or more digits (0-9)
(?=\-)   # Look after the group for a hyphen, but don't add it to the capture group.
```

Comment: `/` is a forward slash, ` \ ` is a backslash.

Comment: can you rewrite the regex as "get the numbers followed by a slash(/) until a dash(-)?

Comment: My bad, I can never get the two of them straight.

Comment: Not a problem! If you want to try your hand at regex in the future, I'd recommend using http://www.regular-expressions.info/, as it has an excellent reference for most (if not all) of the regex rules.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this as your regular expression: `/\/([0-9]+)/`

Comment: I think a regex as "get the numbers followed by a slash(/) until a dash(-) would be better

Comment: That's not what your question asked though: "IF the url has a slash followed by numbers".